# Is there something like UITableView?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I've found that exist **List Box**, but I can't find good example how to use it.
And than can I do something like when I scrolled to bottom my ListBox, I need to add new rows, also I need to do some logic when user has clicked on row.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
To have a ListBox that loads items when scrolling reaches the bottom, you must implement something called LazyList.
I've done something like that myself.

You can use this LazyCollection as DataSource for the ListBox:

```
public class LazyCollection<T> : IList<T>, IList, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const int LOAD_THRESHOLD = 3;

    private ObservableCollection<T> _innerCollection;

    public LazyCollection(Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> fetch)
        : this(fetch, null)
    { }

    public LazyCollection(Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> fetch, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        _fetch = fetch;
        _innerCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>(items ?? new T[0]);
        this.AttachEvents();
        this.HasMoreItems = true;
    }

    private void AttachEvents()
    {
        _innerCollection.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => OnCollectionChanged(e);
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)_innerCollection).PropertyChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
            this.CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }
    #endregion

    #region IList<T>
    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return _innerCollection.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        _innerCollection.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _innerCollection.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - Reading item {0}", index);
            return _innerCollection[index];
        }
        set { _innerCollection[index] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _innerCollection.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _innerCollection.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _innerCollection.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _innerCollection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _innerCollection.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return ((IList<T>)_innerCollection).IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return _innerCollection.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - GetEnumerator");
        return _innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - GetEnumerator explicit");
        return ((IEnumerable)_innerCollection).GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IList
    int IList.Add(object value)
    {
        return ((IList)_innerCollection).Add(value);
    }

    bool IList.Contains(object value)
    {
        return ((IList)_innerCollection).Contains(value);
    }

    int IList.IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return ((IList)_innerCollection).IndexOf(value);
    }

    void IList.Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        ((IList)_innerCollection).Insert(index, value);
    }

    bool IList.IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return ((IList)_innerCollection).IsFixedSize; }
    }

    bool IList.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return ((IList)_innerCollection).IsReadOnly; }
    }

    void IList.Remove(object value)
    {
        ((IList)_innerCollection).Remove(value);
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index > this.Count - LOAD_THRESHOLD)
            {
                this.TryLoadMoreItems();
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - Reading item {0} IList", index);
            return ((IList)_innerCollection)[index];
        }
        set { ((IList)_innerCollection)[index] = value; }
    }

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        ((IList)_innerCollection).CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return ((IList)_innerCollection).IsSynchronized; }
    }

    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get { return ((IList)_innerCollection).SyncRoot; }
    }
    #endregion

    public T[] GetLoadedItems()
    {
        return _innerCollection.ToArray();
    }

    public void ResetLoadedItems(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        _innerCollection.Clear();
        foreach (var i in list)
            _innerCollection.Add(i);
        this.HasMoreItems = true;
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems { get; set; }
    private bool _isLoading = false;
    private Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> _fetch;

    private async Task TryLoadMoreItems()
    {
        if (_isLoading || !this.HasMoreItems)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isLoading = true;

            Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - Loading more items skip {0}", this.Count);
            List<T> items = _fetch != null ? (_fetch(Count)).ToList() : new List<T>();

            if (items.Count == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - No items returned, Loading disabled", this.Count);
                this.HasMoreItems = false;
            }

            items.ForEach(x => _innerCollection.Add(x));

            Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - Items added. Total count: {0}", this.Count);
        }
        finally
        {
            _isLoading = false;
        }


    }
}
```

Here's how you use it

```
var functionThatProvidesData = (indexFromWhereToStart)=> 
        {
            //Here you do the part that provides data to your List and Skip the items that
            // are already provided and take as many as you decide to take.
            return MyDataSource.Skip(indexFromWhereToStart).Take(30 or more);
        }
LazyCollection<MyObjectType> myDataSource = new LazyCollection<MyObjectType>(functionThatProvidesData);
lboMyListBox.ItemsSource = myDataSource;
```

As About your event when clicking an Item there are multiple ways to do it

- `Tap` event on each item in the `ItemTemplate`
- `SelectionChanged` on the ListBox **doesn't work when you click an item that is already selected**

XAML code:

```
<ListBox Margin="50" Name="lboMyListBox" SelectionChanged="lboMyListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="15" Tap="Item_Tap">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

#### Note

You must have your event handler in the Code behind for the XAML to be compiled.

Comment: what about XAML code?

Comment: Thanks, i try to use your code

Comment: But what about to fill this listBox when i geting data from server ? After i have array with my data, how i can to fill it?

Comment: You can make the retrieving of data Asynchronous in the part that provides data to the List. If you need specific guidance on how to do that you should provide the code you are using to retrieve data from Server